# Geolocation Api to find state name and district name

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am currently using **javascript geolocation api** to fetch lat long of the current position of the user and display the name of the position in my project. I also want to get **the state name and district name** from that and store them in some variables so that i can use them for the further searches that i am creating in my project. So please help me out in finding the state name and district name separately of the current location of user.

Comment: Till now I am finding the lat long of the user's location by using javascript api and then displayed the name of the location in a label.  Now I want to fetch state name and district name from that location name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Maps API and make a request like the following:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=yourlatvalue,yourlangvalue&sensor=false

This will return you a json file with all the relevant info you need.

For example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

Comment: District is not in the link